# How much does each specialist reduce the waiting time on resources?

Tags: reignmaker

In ReignMaker you can hire the following specialists via your town hall:

- Lumberjack
- Farmer
- Scholar
- Armsmaster
- Smelter

Each of them supposedly reduces the waiting/production time on resources and/or Spells and Equipment. The game fails to tell us by how much though. Does anyone have any numbers on this?

[image: Screenshot of the hire section]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will reduce the production time by 1% each. You can have a maximum of 20 for each specialist, so a reduction of 20% in total for each field. Source is the developer himself, from the first comment [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/286200/discussions/0/540739861087429683/).